# How to determine which team won and add to it 3 point if it won, 0 if lose, and 1 if draw

Tags: javascript

I have array of game results, I need to determine based on score how many points to add to teams. In this example France get 3 points, Croatia 0 and England and Spain both 1 point. How this can be implemented, can anyone help?

```
const matches = [
    {
        homeTeam: 'France',
        awayTeam: 'Croatia',
        score: '2:1',
        date: '18.01.2019'
    },
      {
        homeTeam: 'England',
        awayTeam: 'Spain',
        score: '1:1',
        date: '18.01.2019'
    }
];

function getRankings(games) {
    // ...implementation
} 

const footbalRankings = getRankings(matches);
console.log(footbalRankings);
```

The output should be as this:

```
[
    { team: 'France', points:  3 }
    { team: 'England', points: 1 }
    { team: 'Spain', points: 1 }
    { team: 'Croatia', points: 0 }
]
```

Comment: Why does France get 3 points and not 2?

Comment: @Markus-ipse I'm assuming that it is a football (soccer in some countries) game, where the victorious team get 3 points.

Comment: That's right, that is football :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const matches = [
  {
    homeTeam: 'France',
    awayTeam: 'Croatia',
    score: '2:1',
    date: '18.01.2019'
  }, {
    homeTeam: 'England',
    awayTeam: 'Spain',
    score: '1:1',
    date: '18.01.2019'
  }
];

function getRankings(games) {
  var ranks = {};
  games.forEach(game => {
    var [homeScore, awayScore] = game.score.split(':');
    if (!ranks[game.homeTeam]) ranks[game.homeTeam] = { name: game.homeTeam, points: 0 };
    if (!ranks[game.awayTeam]) ranks[game.awayTeam] = { name: game.awayTeam, points: 0 };
    if (homeScore > awayScore) {
      ranks[game.homeTeam].points += 3;
    } else if (awayScore > homeScore) {
      ranks[game.awayTeam].points += 3;
    } else {
      ranks[game.homeTeam].points++;
      ranks[game.awayTeam].points++;
    }
  });
  return Object.values(ranks).sort((a, b) => a.points > b.points ? -1 : 1);
} 
        
var footbalRankings = getRankings(matches);
console.log(footbalRankings);
```

Comment: Nice solution, I was about to do something similar, however I would recommend 2 things. First is to sort the resulting array because the outcome isn't exactly as the OP asked. The second thing is that it would be nice if you could embed the snippet with your solution so the OP can run and check the result.

Comment: I have to update my solution because there are some simple mistakes. I'll see if I can't include these suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFontes Thanks so much for the suggestion! Let me know what you think! :D

Comment: @DillanWilding Looks great to me :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a function `calculatePoints()` which takes match score and calculates points for both teams.

Use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to keep track of total points for each team. `Map` also preserves insertion order of the keys.

Then convert the results from `Map` to desired array format and sort by points.

```js
const matches = [{ homeTeam: 'France', awayTeam: 'Croatia', score: '2:1', date: '18.01.2019' }, { homeTeam: 'England', awayTeam: 'Spain', score: '1:1', date: '18.01.2019' } ];

function getRankings(matches) {
  let rankings = new Map();
  let result = [];

  matches.forEach(match => {
    let totalA = rankings.get(match.homeTeam) || 0;
    let totalB = rankings.get(match.awayTeam) || 0;

    let points = calculatePoints(match.score);

    rankings.set(match.homeTeam, totalA + points.homeTeam);
    rankings.set(match.awayTeam, totalB + points.awayTeam);
  });

  // Convert result to array format.
  for (let [key, value] of rankings.entries()) {
    result.push({ "team": key, "points": value });
  }
  
  // Sort results by points.
  return result.sort((a, b) => b.points - a.points);
}

// Takes match score and calculates points for both teams.
function calculatePoints(matchScore) {
  let [teamA, teamB] = matchScore.split(":");
  let pointsA = 0, pointsB = 0;

  if (teamA > teamB) {
    pointsA = 3;
  } else if (teamA < teamB) {
    pointsB = 3;
  } else {
    pointsA = 1;
    pointsB = 1;
  }

  return { "homeTeam": pointsA, "awayTeam": pointsB };
}

const footballRankings = getRankings(matches);

console.log(footballRankings);
```

Comment: I am wondering which solution is better according to time and space complexity, is there a way and can it be determined which solution is more optimal?

Comment: @Pokreniseweb - When dealing with small amounts of data it wouldn't matter. You can use [jsperf](https://jsperf.com) to compare if interested. But if order of insertion is important then use maps. Also if the keys are unknown, it is better to use maps because object is fragile and gives unexpected output in cases such as these. For example, try the other answer with a team named `constructor` and see the output.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions.